# Inserting from a multidimensional associative array into multiple tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, sql-insert

I've been at this for the better part of two days without making much progress. I've found tons of help here and elsewhere but can't quite figure out how to get it all to play together.

I'm developing a simple database for recipes i found round the web and want to save.

A form is being populated by parsing a URL for recipe details and then some manual pruning, adding and editing. Each recipe has some basic info, a number of ingredients and a set of instructions. These go in to three different tables and are all being connected via a "recipe_id".

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to take the array from the from and:

- get some of the fields into one table as one row
- get the 3-part ingredients into another table as several rows
- and finally instructions into a third table as several rows.

This is the $_POST from the form:

```
array(47) { 
["title"]=> string(33) "Hot and Fruity Caribbean Coleslaw" 
["description"]=> string(11) "Lorem ipsum" 
["credits"]=> string(11) "Lorem ipsum" 
["url"]=> string(69) "http://thehappyfoodie.co.uk/recipes/hot-and-fruity-caribbean-coleslaw" 
["category"]=> string(1) "1" 
["cuisine"]=> string(1) "1" 
["yield"]=> string(10) "8 servings" 
["time_prep"]=> string(2) "10" 
["time_cook"]=> string(2) "10" 
["time_total"]=> string(2) "20"
["ingredient_quant_0"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_0"]=> string(1) "8" 
["ingredient_0"]=> string(17) "1/2 Savoy cabbage" 
["ingredient_quant_1"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_1"]=> string(2) "11" 
["ingredient_1"]=> string(17) "1/2 white cabbage" 
["ingredient_quant_2"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_2"]=> string(1) "-" 
["ingredient_2"]=> string(21) "1/2 red onion, peeled" 
["ingredient_quant_3"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_3"]=> string(1) "8" 
["ingredient_3"]=> string(15) "1/2 small mango" 
["ingredient_quant_4"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_4"]=> string(1) "-" 
["ingredient_4"]=> string(20) "3 tsp French mustard" 
["ingredient_quant_5"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_5"]=> string(1) "-" 
["ingredient_5"]=> string(19) "100ml cider vinegar" 
["ingredient_quant_6"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_6"]=> string(1) "-" 
["ingredient_6"]=> string(29) "8 tbsp soft light brown sugar" 
["ingredient_quant_7"]=> string(3) "100" 
["ingredient_uom_7"]=> string(2) "10" 
["ingredient_7"]=> string(15) "100ml olive oil" 
["ingredient_quant_8"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_8"]=> string(1) "-" 
["ingredient_8"]=> string(15) "Salt and pepper" 
["ingredient_quant_9"]=> string(1) "1" 
["ingredient_uom_9"]=> string(1) "9" 
["ingredient_9"]=> string(54) "1/2 tbsp X Hot Reggae Reggae Sauce or hot chilli sauce" 
["ingredient_quant_10"]=> string(0) "" 
["ingredient_uom_10"]=> string(1) "-" 
["ingredient_10"]=> string(48) "2 red chillies, seeded and cut into fine slivers" 
["instruction_0"]=> string(177) "Remove and discard the cabbage cores and finely shred the leaves. Slice the onion wafer-thin using a mandolin if you have one. Peel the mango and cut the flesh into matchsticks." 
["instruction_1"]=> string(265) "Put the mustard, vinegar and sugar in a jam jar. Screw on the lid and give it a good shake. Add the oil, salt, pepper and hot sauce. Shake again then poor into a large serving bowl. Toss in the cabbage, onion, mango and chillies and mix well. Taste for seasoning." 
["image"]=> string(127) "https://flockler.com/thumbs/sites/192/127_grillitlevi_hotandfruitycoleslaw-smaller_s1200x630_c1500x876_l0x482_q80_noupscale.jpg"
```

I then pass that array to a function and try to break it up into the parts that should go into the different tables:

```
function addnewrecipe($postArray) {
    var_dump($postArray);


    // Test and clean user input
    $cleanedArray = array();
    foreach ($postArray as $postKey => $postValue) {
        $cleanValue = test_input($postArray[$postKey]);
        $cleanedArray[$postKey] = $cleanValue;
    }

    // Map form post names to those in the DB
    $mappingArray = array(
        'title' => 'name',
        'description' => 'description',
        'credits' => 'author',
        'url' => 'url',
        'category' => 'category_id',
        'cuisine' => 'cuisine_id',
        'yield' => 'yield',
        'time_prep' => 'preptime',
        'time_cook' => 'cooktime',
        'time_total' => 'totaltime',
        'image' => 'image'
    );

    // Create a final array with used form fields and clean input
    $finalArray = array();
    foreach($mappingArray as $formKey => $dbKey) {
        if(!empty($cleanedArray[$formKey])) {
            $finalArray[$dbKey] = $cleanedArray[$formKey];
        }
    }




    //Connect to DB
    $conn = connDB();

    // Begin transaction
    try {

        $conn->autocommit(FALSE); 

        $recipeKey = array_keys($finalArray);
        $recipeValue = array_values($finalArray);
        $query = "INSERT INTO recipes (" . implode(', ', $recipeKey) . ") " . "VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $recipeValue) . "')";
        //echo $query;
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if ( !$result ) {
            $result->free();
            throw new Exception($conn->error);
        }

        $recipe_id = $conn->insert_id; // last auto_inc id from *this* connection

        //$query = "INSERT INTO ingredients (recipe_id,ingredient,uom_id,ingredient_quant) ";
        //$query .= "VALUES ('$recipe_id','$ingredient')";
        //$result = $conn->query($query);
        //if ( !$result ) {
        //  $result->free();
        //  throw new Exception($conn->error);
        //}

        $conn->commit();
        $conn->autocommit(TRUE); // i.e., end transaction
    }
    catch ( Exception $e ) {

        $conn->rollback(); 
        $conn->autocommit(TRUE); // i.e., end transaction   
    }

    $conn->close();
```

It works ok for the basic info although I have a feeling i've over complicated it slightly. I first check the input for unsafe stuff and then re-map the key/column names from the form to those in the DB and create a new array `$finalArray` with the clean result omitting the instructions and the ingredients.

That then goes into a standard INSERT statement and i can go on to prepare to insert the ingredients and the instructions. But this is where i've confused myself.

Each recipe will have a different number of ingredients. Each ingredient has three values and two of then can be NULL. They will be referenced by "recipe_id" from the previous insert which works fine like this: `$recipe_id = $conn->insert_id;` but how can i get the three values for each of the ingredients and insert them as one row? I've tried

```
$ingredientArray = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 5) {
        if (isset($cleanedArray["ingredient_" . $i])) {
            $ingredientArray["ingredient_" . $i] = $cleanedArray["ingredient_" . $i];
        }

        if (isset($cleanedArray["uom_id_" . $i])) {
            $ingredientArray["uom_id_" . $i] = $cleanedArray["uom_id_" . $i];
        }

        if (isset($cleanedArray["ingredient_quant_" . $i])) {
            $ingredientArray["ingredient_quant_" . $i] = $cleanedArray["ingredient_quant_" . $i];
        }
     $i++;
     }
     //var_dump($ingredientArray);
```

to get them out but not knowing how many there might be makes the approach rather questionable i guess.

I feel like this shouldn't be that hard. I've got a fairly simple array with values and the seemingly simple task of splitting that array up and inserting it into the right tables. Any help as to how to approach this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The difficulty is in how your data is organized. If you have access to the other part of the application, **reorganize** the data to help you program. The ingredients should be in it's own node of the array, and within the ingredients node you would have a single ingredient array for each ingredient with the 3 fields  you are speaking of.

Comment: You should be using an array for your ingredients in the form ie `<input type="text" name="ingredient[1][name]" /> <input type="text" name="ingredient[1][quant]" /> <input type="text" name="ingredient[1][uom]" />` this will help you greatly

Comment: I don't think you should have a value like "1/2 savoy cabbage". You should have an ingredient like "savoy cabbage" and a quantity (like 1/2). There might also be a unit column (which in this case would be null or blank, but contain 'tsp','tbp', etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on string manipulation to figure out which ingredient belongs to which field like you are currently:

```
array(
    // .... some other stuff above
    "ingredient_quant_0"    =>  "" 
    "ingredient_uom_0"  =>  "8" ,
    "ingredient_0"          => "1/2 Savoy cabbage" ,
    "ingredient_quant_1"    =>  "blah" ,
    "ingredient_uom_1"  =>  "11" ,
    "ingredient_1"          => "1/2 Ricotta Cheese" ,
    "ingredient_quant_2"    =>  "" ,
    "ingredient_uom_2"  =>  "12" ,
    "ingredient_2"          => "2 Chilis" ,
)
```

Structure your post data so that the ingredients are grouped together like so:

```
array(
    // .... some other stuff above
    "ingredients" => array(
        [0] => array( "quant" => "", "uom" => "8", "ingredient" => "1/2 Savoy cabbage"),
        [1] => array( "quant" => "blah", "uom" => "11", "ingredient" => "1/2 Ricotta Cheese"),
        [2] => array( "quant" => "", "uom" => "12", "ingredient" => "2 Chilis"),
    ) 
 )
```

The HTML would be something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ingredients[0]['ingredient']>
<input type="text" name="ingredients[0]['uom']>
<input type="text" name="ingredients[0]['quant']>
<hr>
<input type="text" name="ingredients[1]['ingredient']>
...
```

Then you can build your insert statement much more easily

```
<?php
$recipe_id = $conn->insert_id; // last auto_inc id from *this* connection
foreach($myPostArray['ingredients'] as $ingredient){
    $query .= "INSERT INTO ingredients (recipe_id,ingredient,uom_id,ingredient_quant) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ( $recipe_id, {$ingredient['ingredient']}, {$ingredient['uom']}, {$ingredient['quant']})";
}
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to have each ingredient in its own array. But it's my understanding that I can't chose how to structure the data when the array is the result of a form submission? Or can I?

Comment: Yes you can, if you have access to the form. Do you?

Comment: In your insert example would I create one query for each ingredient and run them one after the other then?

Comment: No, Just get the long sql string built and run the query all at once. Otherwise you would be making multiple calls to your database which = slower

Comment: Yes, I have complete access to the form. So I can specify the desired array structure directly in the form then? Like so: `<input type='text'  name='ingredients[$i]' />`

Comment: Pretty much yep, I edited my answer to add in the ingredients html groups

Comment: Many thanks for your help @Chizzle . I'm having some trouble with the combined statements from your and my previous insert giving me an error ´Call to a member function free() on a non-object´ but I reckon i will have a solution for that soon. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! `echo` out your `$query` and make sure it's valid SQL. Probably something small!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ingredientArray = [];
$i = 0;
while ($i < 5) {
    $ingredientArray[] = [
        'name' => isset($cleanedArray["ingredient_" . $i]) ? $cleanedArray["ingredient_" . $i] : null,
        'quantity' => isset($cleanedArray["ingredient_quantity_" . $i]) ? $cleanedArray["ingredient_quantity_" . $i] : null
        // etc.
    ];
}
```